# C# EF Code First Include always returns Null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have three entities connected on 1-N Relation, Persons is populated correctly and ID types id are populated correctly. PersonIDEntity is saved correctly to the database with the correct PersonID and TypeID.

However when I load the PersonIDEntity neither TypesID nor Person is loaded during the Include statement. Tried to have the navigation properties virtual did not solve the problem.

I'm using EF Core 7 in a WPF project.

During troubleshooting, I found the following error :

1st Entity (relevant properties are shown):

```
public class Persons : IEntities<Persons>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The row ID of the person in the Database
    /// </summary>
    public int ID { get; set; }

    .....

    /// <summary>
    /// List of Official Documents of the Person
    /// </summary>
    public  List<PersonsIDEntity>? PersonsIDEntity { get; set; }
}

public class IDTypes : IEntities<IDTypes>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ......
    public ObservableCollection<PersonsIDEntity>? PersonsIDEntity { get; set; } 
}

public class PersonsIDEntity : IEntities<PersonsIDEntity>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ID of the Row. Assigned by SQL
    /// </summary>
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Type of the ID
    /// </summary>
    public int IDTypeID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Is the ID Active
    /// </summary>
    public Persons Persons { get; set; } 
    public IDTypes IDTypes { get; set; }
}
```

The code to load the data:

```
public ObservableCollection<PersonsIDEntity> GetCollectionByType(int ID)
{
    BaseDbContext context = new BaseDbContext();

    ObservableCollection<PersonsIDEntity> entity = new ObservableCollection<PersonsIDEntity>      (context.PersonsIDEntity.Where(x => x.IDTypeID == ID).Include("Persons").ToList());

    return entity;
}
```

Builder class :

```
public class PersonsIDConfiguration:IEntityTypeConfiguration< PersonsIDEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PersonsIDEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(e => e.Persons)
             .WithMany(e => e.PersonsIDEntity)
             .HasForeignKey(e => e.PersonID)
             .HasPrincipalKey(e=> e.ID);
        builder.HasOne(e => e.IDTypes)
            .WithMany(e => e.PersonsIDEntity)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.IDTypeID);
    }
}
```

SQL Server tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons] 
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonAssignedTypesID] INT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Persons] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Persons_PersonAssignedTypes_PersonAssignedTypesID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([PersonAssignedTypesID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PersonAssignedTypes] ([ID])
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Persons_PersonAssignedTypesID]
ON [dbo].[Persons]([PersonAssignedTypesID] ASC);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IDTypes] 
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    .....
    CONSTRAINT [PK_IDTypes] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonsIDEntity] 
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    ......
    [PersonID] INT NOT NULL,
    [IDTypeID] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PersonsIDEntity] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PersonsIDEntity_IDTypes_IDTypeID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[IDTypes] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PersonsIDEntity_Persons_PersonID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([PersonID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Persons] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PersonsIDEntity_IDTypeID]
ON [dbo].[PersonsIDEntity]([IDTypeID] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PersonsIDEntity_PersonID]
ON [dbo].[PersonsIDEntity]([PersonID] ASC);
```

I rebuild the database, made the navigation properties virtual. However I get the following message if I put a breakpoint after the query:

> ((System.RuntimeType)((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ConstructorBinding)((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Runti...NSPersons.PersonsIDEntity>)context.PersonsIDEntity).Local._entityType).ServiceOnlyConstructorBinding).RuntimeType).DeclaringMethod = '((System.RuntimeType)((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ConstructorBinding)((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RuntimeEntityType)((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<Entities.NSPersons.PersonsIDEntity>)context.PersonsIDEntity)....

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, especially I have other includes in the Project which are indeed correctly loaded ?

Comment: This may be a typo in the question but aren't you missing the setter in `public  List<PersonsIDEntity>? PersonsIDEntity { get; }`

Comment: This missing when i asked the question, but I added it but the issuer persists.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code: You dont't need to make virtual any property.

I added, inside your BaseDbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   new PersonsIDentityConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<PersonsIDEntity>());
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

because You didn't show it. So You are sure to apply the fluent API configuration.

The right code to include and load childs (Persons) is:

```
int idToSearch = 1;  //if You want to include the first ID Person
List<PersonsIDEntity> listSearch = db.PersonsIDEntities.Where(c => c.IDTypeID == idToSearch).Include("Persons").ToList();

Console.WriteLine(listSearch[0].Persons.Name); //if You have a "Name" property
```

It works perfectly.